# Get {} as an output instead of []

Tags: php, json, kohana

I have service which returns the menu of venues, but if menu is not exist, I should return {} as an output, otherwise ios app cannot parse the response and app destroys.
Now reponse looks like:

```
{
    "response": []
}
```

I should have

```
{
    "response": {}
}
```

API services programmed with PHP. 
When menu empty url: http://ilovejetset.com/api/v2/menu/index/422
When some menu exist: http://ilovejetset.com/api/v2/menu/index/423

The code for creating response:
in 'after' function:

```
$this->response->body(json_encode(array('response' => $this->response_json)));
```

when no menu:

```
$this->response_json = array();
```

Comment: nothing matters both are arrays?

Comment: Do you have a question to us? Show the code that is not working for you

Comment: I cannot formate second array

Comment: @user3815581 just show us the code that you use to create the json response.

Comment: I see you finally added your code. I thikn jshthornton's answer will suit you best. And a quick work around would be to change `array()` into `(object)array()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this page:
[Predefined Constants (JSON)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php) More specifically `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`

If the data which is deeper than `responses` needs to be an array then you will need to loop over first encode all of that data, then encode the top layer.

[image]

```
$test = array(
    "responses" => array()
);

echo json_encode($test, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: I think you have an issue your side then. It is working for me, check the image.

Comment: If you're doing API development, can I interest you in this utility script: https://github.com/jshthornton/Parallelbug

Comment: `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` will force *everything* to be an object though. `array('foo')` will become `{"0":"foo"}`. That's not always desired.

Comment: @deceze I know, I put a quick aside regarding that. OP never mentioned that he needed it so I didn't go into it further.

Answer (score -1):

If you need an object, then you need to create an object in PHP as well. As long as you're using arrays, PHP will preferably encode them as JSON arrays.

```
$data = new stdClass;
$data->foo = 'bar';

echo json_encode(array($data));
```

or:

```
echo json_encode(array((object)array('foo' => 'bar')));
```

Comment: can I create empty object? it should be just {}

Comment: Yes, `new stdClass` or `(object)array()` will be an empty object.

Answer (score -1):

if you use **json_encode** this function, you can try to add the option JSON_FORCE_OBJECT as fllows.

```
<?php
$var = array();
$var['response'] = array();
echo json_encode($var, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

$var1 = array();
$var1['response'] = array();
$var1['response']['name'] = 'jediliang';
echo json_encode($var1, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

the output looks like this:

```
{"response":{}}{"response":{"name":"jediliang"}}
```

Answer (score -1):

For more clarification try this following example

```
class a {
    var $name;
};
$a = new a;
$a->name = array("name"=>"fname");
echo json_encode(array("a"=> $a, "name"=>array("fname","lname")));
```

Hope it clears all your doubts